# How to get cookiecutter to output to current working directory instead of nested directory?

Tags: cookiecutter

We have a number of use cases where we'd like to be able to call cookiecutter and have the files and directories generated get put into the current working directory.

### Simple example

What is essentially desired.

```
$ cd path/to/repo
$ ls
a.txt
$ cookiecutter path/to/template
$ls
a.txt b.txt
```

What the result actually is

```
$ cd path/to/repo
$ ls
a.txt
$ cookiecutter path/to/template
$ls
a.txt 
template/
  b.txt
```

### Things I've tried

1. You could imagine the template being something like this.

```
template/
  cookiecutter.json
  b.txt
```

But cookiecutter appears to require there to be a template root by default to avoid `cookiecutter.exceptions.NonTemplatedInputDirException`.

2. So, add a directory to contain the template files and try and output it to a particular directory.

```
template/
  cookiecutter.json
  {{cookiecutter.name}}
```

But then the template files are just nested in a subdirectory of the current working directory like shown above of course.

3. I also expect one could use a post-generate hook to move the template's output files to where you want, but that seems like a bit of a hack...

I keep seeing comments on GitHub saying basically "this is solved", but I can't seem to find documentation on how to use whatever feature was added to accommodate this use case.

- https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/issues/1068
- https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/issues/35
- https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter/issues/153

Answer (score 6):

The issue is closed, but this doesn't mean it is solved.

The only way to do this is with post-generate hook moving the files out of your folder and deleting the folder.

If you are on a *NIX system, you can use the following simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh

mv * ..
rm -rfv ../{{ cookiecutter.project_name }}
```

Where `cookiecutter.project_name` is your template folder.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71038418/7256443), which should work perfectly on linux/mac, here is a solution in pure python

`hooks/post_gen_project.py`:

```py
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path, PurePath
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory


def _move_single_file(src_dir: PurePath, dst_dir: PurePath, file_name: str):
    shutil.move(
        str(src_dir.joinpath(file_name)),
        dst_dir.joinpath(file_name),
        copy_function=lambda x, y: shutil.copytree(
            x, y, dirs_exist_ok=True, copy_function=shutil.copy2
        ),
    )


def move_directory_contents(src: PurePath, dst: PurePath):
    temp_dir = TemporaryDirectory()
    temp_dir_path = Path(temp_dir.name)

    directory_contents = os.listdir(src)
    for item in directory_contents:
        print(f"Moving {item} to {temp_dir_path}")
        _move_single_file(src, temp_dir_path, item)

    directory_contents.remove(src.name)

    for item in directory_contents:
        print(f"Moving {item} to {dst}")
        _move_single_file(temp_dir_path, dst, item)

    os.removedirs(src)

    _move_single_file(temp_dir_path, dst, src.name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if "{{ cookiecutter.use_current_directory }}".lower() == "y":
        src = Path.cwd()
        assert src.name == "{{ cookiecutter.project_slug }}"
        move_directory_contents(src, src.parent)
```

and the `cookiecutter.json` will need to have this line:

```json
{
  "use_current_directory": "y/n",
}
```

This should work on any OS and only requires the `hooks/post_gen_project.py`